# How to speed up this Postgres query by reducing the number of rows it has to search through before it searches?

Tags: postgresql

**Context:**
I have three Postgres tables:

1. authors - stores the id, author's full name, credentials, and awards
2. books - stores the id, title, book-length, summary, and an image of the front cover
3. authorBookRelations - connects Authors and Books by storing the author_id and book_id

An author can be connected to any book, but books are not connected. Books can have the same name, but each has its own id that is unique. Multiple authors can author a single book.

**My question:**
If I want to get all titles that match a given list of titles and are by a specific author what would be the best way to do that?

**What I have so far:**
Currently, I do two SELECT queries and a filtering function to "join" the two queries.
SELECT query #1 - get all of the book_ids associated with a particular author:
`SELECT book_id FROM authorBookRelations WHERE author_id = 5`


SELECT query #2 - get all of the titles that are in a given list of titles:
`SELECT * FROM books WHERE title IN ('arbitraryTitle_1', arbitraryTitle_2, etc.)`


Filter function (python) - filter titles for any that are not written by that specific author:
`filtered_list = [x for x in query_2_results if x.id in query_1_results]`

I get the correct books with this method, but can't help but feel that this is not a good way to do it/won't scale well. What would you suggest as a way to speed up this query? Instead of two separate db calls and a filtering function, could I do it all in one call by searching the list of titles against the filtered rows in table "books" that were filtered by the output from the query against authorBookRelations? ... that was horribly worded ... so something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT book_id
    FROM authorBookRelations
    WHERE author_id = 5) AS foobar
WHERE title IN ('arbitraryTitle_1', arbitraryTitle_2, etc.)
```

UPDATE:
Trying out this seems to have cut my total query/processing time by half:

```
select *
from (select *
    from books
    where id in (
    select book_id
    from authorBookRelations
    where author_id = 5
    )) as foo
where foo.title in ('arbitraryTitle_1', 'arbitraryTitle_2', etc.)
```

Comment: The magic word is "join". Write a query that joins the three tables and filter with the appropriate `WHERE` condition. Good performance may require indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of performances will be on the "IN" operator, if the list has a great number of items...

For two or three sometime an index can be used by PG for seeking the data.

But when there is much more items, a scan will be the only solution...

If you want to speed up this query, just use a temporary table to INSERT your data into, the add an index and rewrite the query with a join between this temp table and your original query...

Comment: Is this similar in thought to what Laurenz Albe commented?

Comment: Laurenz Albe didn't talk about transforming the list of data from the "IN" operator into an instantiated table, like a temporary one